# Capturing variable using event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I simply wish to capture the options value at the time of change.

My code works when ran in console as individual lines however even after the function is called the variable listObj and eventValue remain null.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("listSelector").addEventListener("change",
    findCarFunc);
  alert("Loaded");
}


function findCarFunc() {

  alert("you changed");

  var listObj = document.getElementById("listSelector");

  var eventValue = listObj.value;

}
```

```html
<select id="listSelector">
  <option value="defaultManufactuer" selected = "selected">Manufacturer</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Now the function returns a string however, I wanted to add quotation marks to string as I am going to use it to identify the relevant element IDs.

Can I actually do what I am attempting to below? I feel I may have confused myself,

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("listSelector").addEventListener("change", populateContainer);
    alert("Loaded");
}

function findCarFunc() {
    alert("you changed");
    var listObj = document.getElementById("listSelector").value;
    console.log(listObj);
}

function populateContainer() {
    alert("Container Event Loaded")
    //Div to append child on once the function has returned the 
    //element string. 
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    //This is where I attempt to capture and manipulate the string by 
    //concatinating the quote marks onto the . 
    var str = "'"+findCarFunc()+"'";
    console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Your code is working as expected... you can put a console in your findCarFunc...

Comment: `document.getElementById("listSelector").options[listObj.selectedIndex].value;` oops late reply.

Comment: Damn object notation, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the **selected** option using
`var eventValue = listObj.options[listObj.selectedIndex].value;`

**Edit**. I have updated my answer to fit your needs mentioned in comments.
The problem with your code is that your are not returning anything in your findCarFunc(), meaning this function will return undefined by default.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("listSelector").addEventListener("change", populateContainer);
    alert("Loaded");
}

function findCarFunc() {
    alert("you changed");
    var listObj = document.getElementById("listSelector").value;
  
    return listObj;
}

function populateContainer() {
    alert("Container Event Loaded")
    //Div to append child on once the function has returned the 
    //element string. 
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    //This is where I attempt to capture and manipulate the string by 
    //concatinating the quote marks onto the . 
    var str = "'"+findCarFunc()+"'";
    console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<select id = "listSelector">
    <option value="defaultManufactuer" selected = "selected">Manufacturer</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can see I missed the object notation for the selected index, TY for clarity.

Comment: If you're not using twenty years old browser, the value of the selected option is reflected to the value of the select element too.

Comment: Thanks, I now have the string and I am attempted to simply add quotation marks before and after the string as to use the concatenated value in order to indentify target elements.

Comment: @Simon Dean check my updated answer. I hope this is what your are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Comment: @SimonDean good to hear it works. If all is fine please mark my answer as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("listSelector").addEventListener("change", findCarFunc);
    alert("Loaded");
}

function findCarFunc() {
    alert("you changed");

    var listObj = document.getElementById("listSelector").value;
    console.log(listObj);
}
```

```html
<select id = "listSelector">
        <option value="defaultManufactuer" selected = "selected">Manufacturer</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: This may sound strange but do you know why the console log may not return in chrome? Seems strange but firebug just returns the value every time I call the function in the console, however, chrome simply states the functions remains undefined along with the variable.